# Acción con hover en Mapa de Palabras SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Tengo este mapa de palabras en svg y necesito que pasen por arriba de una de las palabras y arroje un div con un texto.
Básicamente no se como hacer el trigger con mouseover para que aparezca el cuadro de txt.
Gracias por la ayuda!

```css
.palabras-transform .palabras:hover {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffa300;
}

.palabras-transform .palabras {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.palabras-transform {
  -ms-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g></g>
  <g class="palabras-transform">
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,80)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PORQUE</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-140,20)rotate(90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ARKANO</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-200,40)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">AHORA</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,50)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ESTÁ</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-80,-40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">HACIENDO</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">SABES</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-150,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">MENTE</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,-70)rotate(-60)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">TELÉFONO</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(10,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PREMIO</text>
<text class="palabras" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,-110)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">VICTORIA</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. Además, el código que compartes no termina de funcionar correctamente, lo que hace más difícil ver el problema.

Comment: Acá dejo el link https://jsfiddle.net/mauriciodtovar/fzarn6ef/
La idea es que cuando pasan por arriba de cada palabra debajo del svg tiene que arrojar un texto con un resultado X que tiene cada palabra. Por ejemplo cuando se produce el hover con la palabra teléfono necesito que debajo aparezca un div que diga "58 REPETICIONES".
Espero que sirva esto! 
Gracias por ayudar!

Comment: ¿Quieres que salga la información de cada `Text` en una especie de popover/tooltip? ¿Dónde se asocia cada `Text` con sus resultados?

Comment: Claro, tipo popover pero sin click con over. Los resultados son estáticos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías seguir el principio de programación DRY (siglas de "*Don't Repeat Yourself*" o "No Te Repitas" en inglés). Puedes simplificar mucho el código que presentas para no tener que repetir tantos métodos en JS/jQuery ni tantos estilos en tu CSS. Algunas ventajas de DRY:

- Elimina redundancia
- Reusabilidad
- Hace el código más fácil de mantener y depurar
- Ocupa menos espacio

Imagina que en lugar de tener 10 textos, tienes 100 o 1.000, ¿vas a repetir las mismas dos funciones 100 ó 1.000 veces? Sería un infierno de programación. Entonces para mejorar el código de tu propia respuesta:

- En CSS, haz selectores un poco más genéricos que se aplicarán a todos los textos de una vez.
- En JS:

  - Pon el valor para cada texto en un data-atributo
  - Generaliza los selectores de jQuery
  - En el `mouseover` lee el data-atributo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".palabras-transform text").on("mouseover", function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text($(this).data("valor") + " REPETICIONES").css("visibility", "visible");
  }).on("mouseout", function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.palabras-transform text:hover {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffa300;
}

.palabras-transform text {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.resultado-repeticion {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
  background: #212322;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.palabras-transform {
  -ms-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="palabras-transform">
    <text class="p01" data-valor="60" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,80)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PORQUE</text>
    <text class="p02" data-valor="65" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-140,20)rotate(90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ARKANO</text>
    <text class="p03" data-valor="70" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-200,40)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">AHORA</text>
    <text class="p04" data-valor="75" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,50)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ESTÁ</text>
    <text class="p05" data-valor="80" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-80,-40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">HACIENDO</text>
    <text class="p06" data-valor="85" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">SABES</text>
    <text class="p07" data-valor="90" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-150,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">MENTE</text>
    <text class="p08" data-valor="95" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,-70)rotate(-60)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">TELÉFONO</text>
    <text class="p09" data-valor="100" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(10,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PREMIO</text>
    <text class="p10" data-valor="110" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,-110)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">VICTORIA</text>
  </g>
</svg>
<span class="resultado-repeticion"> </span>
```

Comment: Alvaro mil gracias por tu ayuda! me sirvió mucho tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma, espero que sirva la respuesta.
Les dejo el ejemplo.
Gracias a todos!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("text.p01").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("60 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p01").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p02").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("65 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p02").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p03").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("70 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p03").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p04").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("75 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p04").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p05").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("80 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p05").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p06").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("85 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p06").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p07").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("90 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p07").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p08").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("95 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p08").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p09").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("100 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p09").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  $("text.p10").mouseover(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").text("110 REPETICIONES")
  });
  $("text.p10").mouseout(function() {
    $("span.resultado-repeticion").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.palabras-transform .p01:hover,
.palabras-transform .p02:hover,
.palabras-transform .p03:hover,
.palabras-transform .p04:hover,
.palabras-transform .p05:hover,
.palabras-transform .p06:hover,
.palabras-transform .p07:hover,
.palabras-transform .p08:hover,
.palabras-transform .p09:hover,
.palabras-transform .p10:hover {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ffa300;
}

.palabras-transform .p01,
.palabras-transform .p02,
.palabras-transform .p03,
.palabras-transform .p04,
.palabras-transform .p05,
.palabras-transform .p06,
.palabras-transform .p07,
.palabras-transform .p08,
.palabras-transform .p09,
.palabras-transform .p10 {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.resultado-repeticion {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
  background: #212322;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.palabras-transform {
  -ms-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(500px, 295px) scale(1.8, 1.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g></g>
  <g class="palabras-transform">
    <text class="p01" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,80)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PORQUE</text>
    <text class="p02" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-140,20)rotate(90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ARKANO</text>
    <text class="p03" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-200,40)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">AHORA</text>
    <text class="p04" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,50)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">ESTÁ</text>
    <text class="p05" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-80,-40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">HACIENDO</text>
    <text class="p06" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,40)rotate(-90)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">SABES</text>
    <text class="p07" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-150,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">MENTE</text>
    <text class="p08" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-190,-70)rotate(-60)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">TELÉFONO</text>
    <text class="p09" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(10,-40)rotate(-45)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">PREMIO</text>
    <text class="p10" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(-60,-110)rotate(0)" style="font-family: SunshineFont;">VICTORIA</text>
  </g>
</svg>
<span class="resultado-repeticion"> </span>
```